# Spliting a name entity into First,Middle and Last Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split a name field into a first middle and last name. I'm having trouble getting it to split since the data entered is not consistant. Some fields are entered as

1. AA CC
2. AA CC BB
3. AA CC. BB
4. BB, AA CC

A being first name , B being last name and C being Middle name.
I am working on SQL Server 2016.

I have tried using PARSENAME but not quite sure what direction to take.
Please let me know what I need to provide.

Comment: Required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: And, as for the question, the simple fact, and TL;DR is: You don't. Unless you can verify from the individual what the correct split it, you are at best guessing and you will get some (very) wrong results.

Comment: The _best_ approach here is probably to _not_ attempt doing this in SQL Server.  Your life would be much easier if you just separate the name components at your original data source.

Answer (score 1):

First eliminate any additional character (.,) by means of replacement, then use blank space as separator as following:

```
SELECT REPLACE('AA CC. BB', '.', ''); 

SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('AA CC BB', ' ');
```

Obviously using the corresponding UPDATE sentences.

Comment: I doubt this going to work. For example I would suggest that the value `'BB, AA CC'` is in the format `{Last Name}, {First Name] {Middle Name(s)}`.